# Best way to return an object as a response in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using `Spring batch` to run a job. I have created a `RestController` that executes this job. However I want this job to be synchronous so I didn't annotate my job execution by `@Async`. It is working fine I am getting the response after job completion only.

The scenario is when writing of this Job is finished, i.e. in the `ItemWriter` I am creating an `object` and setting its values, so when this writer is finished I want to return this `object` as a response body.

I know I can do this by creating a shared structure but I don't want to do this.

**What is the best and standard way to do this?**

Comment: Return `Map<String, Object>`

Comment: Yes that's an option, but how this Map<String, Object> be accessed back to the runner from where I am launching the job? so that I can serialize and return it as a response? By putting it in execution context?

Comment: This means your web controller will have to wait for the job to finish to return a response to the caller. Is that really what you want? What if the job takes minutes or hours to run? This is possible from a technical point of view, but no a good choice IMO from a design perspective. If you really know what you do and you want to do it that way, then the answer by `Mohammed Fataka` is the way to go.

Comment: Actually, the requirement is like this only, there is a threshold set for the response. The job would be in such a way that it should not take more time than expected. What's your suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1):

you can put an object in ExecutionContext, then retrieve it from

```
final var executionContext = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(id_of_job).getExecutionContext();
final var object = executionContext.get("key");
```

or

use job launcher to lunch it and then get it from execution context again.

```
final var runJob = launcher.run(job.job(), jobParameters);
final var object = runJob.getExecutionContext().get("key");
```

although this is not recommended for huge response types, but in your case this might be useful

Comment: Yes thanks for this, but this option I am trying to avoid as of now. Because it persists the data, may be some other better option?